# Is Proguard compatible with the $py.class files produced by Jython's py_compile module?

Tags: proguard, jython

Title kind of says it all... I am using Jython's [`py_compile`](http://www.jython.org/docs/library/py_compile.html) to compile a bunch of Python modules to Java `$py.class` files, and was wondering if Proguard can be used to obfuscate these.